# Connect Java app thru proxy with authentification

Tags: java

I have a Java app that has to connect thru a proxy to some addresses.
This is what I've tried:

```java
final String authUser = "xxx";
final String authPassword = "xxx";
Authenticator.setDefault(
new Authenticator(){
   public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordauthentication(){
       return new PasswordAuthentication(
       authUser, authPassword.toCharArray());
   }
});

System.setProperty("http.proxyUser", authUser);
System.setProperty("http.proxyPassword",authPassword);
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost","xxx");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort","8080");
```

After I run the program it gives me this exception:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Is it correct how I tried to connect through the proxy and authenticate?

Comment: Which client API do you use?

Comment: The Api client that is use is OAuth

Comment: What I mean, do you use direct Socket access, Java 11 HttpClient, Apache HttpClient, Netty HttpClient, Spring RestTemplate, Spring WebClient, Jersey Client, Feign Client, JAX-WS Client,... to access the remote addresses/ services?

Comment: FYI (should fit your needs)... https://blogs.oracle.com/wssfc/handling-proxy-server-authentication-requests-in-java